# PHP json_decode and foreach invalid argument

Tags: php

I try to `foreach` a json array from my database.

here is the data:

```
$data = "["B015f6c48c43b7494", "B69036e96dccae075"]";
```

Here is the step I do:

```
$result=[];
$decode = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($decode as $row){
   array_push($result, ['id'=>$row]);
}
return $result;
```

But it return me this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Any solution?

---

I've tried `dd`the $decode this is the result:

```
array:2 [
   0 => "B015f6c48c43b7494"
   1 => "B69036e96dccae075"
]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem using this code: http://pastebin.com/HQR2UpdB BTW, you quote marks here are a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having an issue with your braces.

Please replace

```
$data = "["B015f6c48c43b7494", "B69036e96dccae075"]";
```

with

```
$data = '["B015f6c48c43b7494", "B69036e96dccae075"]';
```

This is the full example:

```
$data = '["B015f6c48c43b7494", "B69036e96dccae075"]';

$result=[];
$decode = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($decode as $row){
   array_push($result, ['id'=>$row]);
}
var_dump($result);
```

And it returns:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string 'B015f6c48c43b7494' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string 'B69036e96dccae075' (length=17)
```

Comment: my $data is came from database. at SO i just type it with "". still get invalid. looks like it came from my database. will look into it first. thanks

Comment: What data you were getting from database. Post it within your question @SSuhat

Comment: Thanks i found the culprit behind it. I use laravel collection so I just realize that some value is not in [] just a single value. that's why when i try to foreach it get the error